# Is the product of group representations commutative?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Consider, for example, the product of $E_6$ representations

$$ 78 \cdot \overline{351}_s \cdot 78 \cdot 351_s, $$

where the $s$ denotes symmetric. Is this equal to

$$ 78 \cdot  78 \cdot \overline{351}_s \cdot 351_s ? $$

Comment: By product do you mean tensor product? If so, then yes.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I mean the ususal product of representations, i.e. for example: $78 \cdot 351_s =  351_a + 351_s +  7371 + 19305$

Comment: So you do mean the tensor product!